# When overloading operators in C++ why is T* preferred over bool?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion, conversion-operator

I have a wrapper class that should behave like a pointer. I have overloaded `operator T*` and `operator bool`. Bool does some extra validation.
I tried using the object inside an if, but I notice that `operator T*` is called and not `bool`. Can someone explain me why? Is this somehow specified in the standard? I tested the sample code below in MSVC, clang and gcc and they all call `operator T*`.
Also, from what I read on this page(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion), the if should try to cast to `bool`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(int i)
        : m(i)
    {}

    operator bool() const
    {
        printf("operator bool()\n");
        return m;
    }

    operator int* ()
    {
        printf("operator int* ()\n");
        return &m;
    }

private:
    int m;
};

int main()
{
    MyClass a(5);
    MyClass b(0);

    if (a)
        printf("a is true\n");
    else
        printf("a is false\n");

    if (b)
        printf("b is true\n");
    else
        printf("b is false\n");

    return 0;
}
```

PS: I also tried with `!!` and `(bool)`, but it still calls `operator int*()`. For `operator bool()`, I have to call it explicitly.

Comment: In the link skip down to the __The safe bool problem__ section.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your class definition the conversion operator `operator bool` is declared with the qualifier `const` but the objects used in the if statements are not constant objects.

```
operator bool() const
                ^^^^^
{
    printf("operator bool()\n");
    return m;
}
```

Remove the qualifier `const` and the operator `operator bool` will be called.

Or declare the conversion operator `operator int *` like

```
operator const int* () const
{
    printf("operator int* ()\n");
    return &m;
}
```

and again the operator `operator bool` will be called.

When an operator has the qualifier const and applied to a non-constant object then one more conversion that is the qualification conversion is required.

Moreover you may declare the operator even as explicit. For example

```
explicit operator bool() 
{
    printf("operator bool()\n");
    return m;
}
```

Comment: To elaborate: the non-const member function wins in overload resolution because it requires fewer conversions than the const member function.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thanks a lot for the quick reply and clarifications!
"When an operator has the qualifier const and applied to a non-constant object then one more conversion that is the qualification conversion is required."

This was what I was missing :)

Comment: @RaduC This conversion is applied to the implicit argument this.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see how to arrive at Vlad's (correct) answer yourself, the process is roughly

1. [`if` statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if)

   The condition is an expression which is contextually convertible to bool
2. [Contextual conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) come under Implicit conversions - note in particular that

   > If there are multiple overloads of the function or operator being called, after the implicit conversion sequence is built from T1 to each available T2, overload resolution rules decide which overload is compiled.

   And then under **Order of the conversions**, that the third step "zero or one standard conversion sequence" comes after the user-defined conversion, and that this step can convert pointer to bool.

   This means that both the user-defined conversion operators are viable for the middle step in that sequence. Finally,
3. [Overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution)

   describes how to select the *best* viable function. Since both operators are viable within the context of the middle step of the conversion sequence, the extra pointer-to-bool conversion that happens *after* this doesn't contribute to the overload ranking.

   Specifically, the ranking is based on the fact that one operator requires const qualification of its implicit first (`this`) parameter, and the other doesn't. This is why a pair of const- and non-const-qualified overloads of the same operator will always choose the overload whose qualification most closely matches the object it's being called on.

Answer (score -5):

I guess you can find specific wording in the standard. Or [this proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2437.pdf)

But I'd say what you want is `explicit operator bool()`

Comment: Please, read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).